# .NET: How to display string as a formatted HTML?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have in my DB a HTML markup written as a strings. How to convert them and view as a formatted HTML markup ? I tried Server.HtmlEncode(), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() with no success

Comment: How are you 'viewing' your html markup? Are you setting the HTML to a label, literal or other control...or are you just doing a Response.Write?

Comment: I'm setting the string into e.g. html label (not asp.net control)

Comment: By "formatted HTML", do you mean you are trying to preserve the markup for viewing, or display the content "rich"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something like what you are after: [Encode and Display HTML - DotNetSlackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/encode_and_display_html_securely_in_asp_net_2_0.aspx)

Comment: The link is broken. I have been seeing this more often on stackoverflow. Dead links help nobody.

Comment: Useless answer - link dead

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to simply output HTML content to a page through ASP.NET. If this is not the case, then I apologize.

You probably want to inject into an [ASP.NET Literal control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx), as opposed to setting a label. If you need the DB HTML put into a label, wrap the label around the DB's content on the server and then fill to literal.

```
<!-- Put into your page where you want it all to happen. -->

<asp:Literal id="labelLiteral" runat="server"/>

...

/* Put into your server code. */

// This would be where your DB content comes from.
String content = "<strong>Some Label:</strong>";

// Wrap the content in a label. Obviously you'll want better format.
String output = String.Format("<label>{0}</label>", content);

// Push the output into the literal.
labelLiteral.Text = output;
```

I hope this helps.